# Can every element really have a class attribute in HTML5, HTML and XHTML?

Tags: xhtml, html

I was wondering if every element can really have a class attribute because if I remember correctly not every element could have a class attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML4 and XHTML, `class` is part of the [core attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#coreattrs), and not every element has the core attributes. For example, `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<title>` don't have a `class` attribute.

In HTML5, every element can have the `class` attribute according to the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#classes).